# Putting multiple objects in Amazon S3 with different meta data fails

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got an array of file information that is being looped through and using the AWS PHP 2 skd to upload the contents of these files to the cloud, it all works brilliantly until I try and add meta data, at this point, it adds the the metadata to the first object created, but after that I get the following error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Aws\S3\Exception\SignatureDoesNotMatchException: AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID: 8FC9360F2EB687EE, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method., User-Agent: aws-sdk-php2/2.2.1 Guzzle/3.3.1 curl/7.24.0 PHP/5.3.13 thrown in D:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ThirdParty_Resources\AWS_SDK2\aws\aws-sdk-php\src\Aws\Common\Exception\NamespaceExceptionFactory.php on line 89

I've cropped the code from my loop to highlight the area that is being naughty.

```
foreach($aFiles as $aFile) {
$arr_ObjectMeta = array(
    'OriginalFileName'  => $aFile['FileName']
,   'Description'       => $aFile['FileDesc']
,   'Keywords'      => $aFile['FileKeyW']
);

// get the file to upload
$obj_FileUpload = $obj_S3->putObject($sBucket, $sBucketFolder . $sFilenameToSave, $sFile, 'public-read', $arr_ObjectMeta);
if($obj_FileUpload) {
    $files_uploaded++;
} else {
    $files_not_uploaded++;
}

// clear the file upload S3 response object
unset($obj_FileUpload);

// delete the downloaded file
unlink($sServerUploadFolder.$sFilenameToSave);
}
```

So the second time around the loop, it seems to bomb because of the different meta values.  When the meta data is the same, the loop executes without issue.  Any help/pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You might be confusing the [putObject method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject) method with the [upload helper method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_upload).

The `upload` helper method is available as of version 2.4 of the SDK. Using the `upload` method you could do the following:

```
try {
    $sKey = $sBucketFolder . $sFilenameToSave;
    $obj_FileUpload = $obj_S3->upload($sBucket, $sKey, $sFile, 'public-read', array(
        'Metadata' => $arr_ObjectMeta
    ));
    $files_uploaded++;
} catch (\Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    $files_not_uploaded++;
}
```

You can do the same thing with the `putObject` method as well, it is just slightly more verbose.

```
try {
    $obj_FileUpload = $obj_S3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'     => $sBucket
        'Key'        => $sBucketFolder . $sFilenameToSave,
        'SourceFile' => $sFile,
        'ACL'        => 'public-read'
        'Metadata'   => $arr_ObjectMeta
    ));
    $files_uploaded++;
} catch (\Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    $files_not_uploaded++;
}
```

Comment: Cheers Jeremy, however, no luck from this at all.  I've got a wrapper for each S3 function that in turn calls the actual required functionality from the S3 client.  So I'd be looking to create a new function that contained a call to this upload function within it, however, when I do, when I call the $this->client->upload from within my accessing function, it just bombs.
There's no actual function I can find within the AWS PHP 2 files in the S3 structure that deals with this functionality, even though it's documented on the official Amazon documentation page.

Comment: It's likely your copy of the SDK is not up to date. I'll update my answer with more specifics and another example.

Comment: Done. The 2nd example with putObject should work without needing to update anything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jeremy, I've updated to 2.4.2, but unfortunately, now nothing is working!  :(
It's complaining about the bucket name not being found, although it works fine on 2.2.1, nightmare.  Anyway, I've got the meta data already stored in the database that would point to the cloud file, so I'm not going to bother with this for the time being as time in ticking.  Thanks for the responses though and attempts to help me with this.

Comment: Weird. I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working for you. If you find any issues, be sure to report them: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues